# How to integrate native ios app design for all iPhones

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am doing Bus ticket booking app. I want to integrate for all iphones. I am facing design problem. how to set image for all iphones.

Comment: google about autolayout in iOS. Study this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/83276/beginning-adaptive-layout-tutorial

Comment: Autolayout + Class Size

Comment: if you are not interested in auto layout use auto resizing method

Comment: I was faced image problem.. Image showed blurr..

Comment: Its because you need to use retina and non-retina image both. Naming convention would be menu.png and menu@2x.png and in your code where you are setting image using [UIImage imagename:@"menu"]

Answer (score 1):

Auto Layout is a system that lets you lay out your app’s user interface by creating a mathematical description of the relationships between the elements. You define these relationships in terms of constraints either on individual elements, or between sets of elements. Using Auto Layout, you can create a dynamic and versatile interface that responds appropriately to changes in screen size, device orientation, and localization.

if you want to design for all ios Devices you have to learn size classes and auto layout I'm giving a link.That will help you

http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1